# How do I add a Moving Average line on top of a candlestick chart in subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, moving-average, legend-properties, mplfinance

**Code**

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplfinance as mpf


# Define the ticker symbol for Apple
ticker_symbol = "AAPL"

# Define the date range (10 years)
start_date_1 = "2013-09-24"
end_date_1 = "2023-09-24"

# Define the date range (5 years)
start_date_2 = "2017-09-24"
end_date_2 = "2023-09-24"

# Define the date range (1 years)
start_date_3 = "2022-09-24"
end_date_3 = "2023-09-24"

# Define the date range (6 month)
start_date_4 = "2023-03-24"
end_date_4 = "2023-09-24"

# Fetch the historical data from Yahoo Finance
apple_ohlc_1 = yf.download(ticker_symbol, start=start_date_1, end=end_date_1, interval="1mo")
apple_ohlc_1["8-Month SMA"] = apple_ohlc_1["Close"].rolling(8).mean()
apple_ohlc_2 = yf.download(ticker_symbol, start=start_date_2, end=end_date_2, interval="1wk")
apple_ohlc_2["40-Week SMA"] = apple_ohlc_2["Close"].rolling(40).mean()
apple_ohlc_3 = yf.download(ticker_symbol, start=start_date_3, end=end_date_3, interval="1d")
apple_ohlc_3["50-Day SMA"] = apple_ohlc_3["Close"].rolling(50).mean()
apple_ohlc_3["200-Day SMA"] = apple_ohlc_3["Close"].rolling(200).mean()
apple_ohlc_4 = yf.download(ticker_symbol, start=start_date_4, end=end_date_4, interval="1d")
apple_ohlc_4["50-Day SMA"] = apple_ohlc_4["Close"].rolling(50).mean()
apple_ohlc_4["200-Day SMA"] = apple_ohlc_4["Close"].rolling(200).mean()

# Create the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(30,22))

# Plot the candlestick chart for the first security on the first axis object
ap = mpf.make_addplot(apple_ohlc_1["8-Month SMA"], color="b", label="8-Month SMA")
mpf.plot(apple_ohlc_2, type='candle', ax=ax[0,0], style='yahoo', xrotation=0, addplot=ap)
ax[0,0].set_title("Apple 10-Year Monthly Chart")
ax[0,0].set_xlabel("Date")
ax[0,0].set_ylabel("Price")
ax[0,0].legend()
ax[0,0].grid()

# Plot the candlestick chart for the second security on the second axis object
mpf.plot(apple_ohlc_2, type='candle', ax=ax[0,1], style='yahoo', xrotation=0)
ax[0,1].set_title("Apple 5-Year Weekly Chart")
ax[0,1].set_xlabel("Date")
ax[0,1].set_ylabel("Price")
ax[0,1].legend()
ax[0,1].grid()


# Plot the candlestick chart for the third security on the third axis object
mpf.plot(apple_ohlc_3, type='candle', ax=ax[1,0], style='yahoo', xrotation=0)
ax[1,0].set_title("Apple 1-Year Daily Chart")
ax[1,0].set_xlabel("Date")
ax[1,0].set_ylabel("Price")
ax[1,0].legend()
ax[1,0].grid()


# Plot the candlestick chart for the fourth security on the fourth axis object
mpf.plot(apple_ohlc_4, type='candle', ax=ax[1,1], style='yahoo', xrotation=0)
ax[1,1].set_title("Apple 6-Month Daily Chart")
ax[1,1].set_xlabel("Date")
ax[1,1].set_ylabel("Price")
ax[1,1].legend()
ax[1,1].grid()
```

**Sample Data**

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume  8-Month SMA
2013-10-01  17.087499618530273  19.258928298950195  17.08142852783203   18.667856216430664  16.29238510131836   7837732000  
2013-11-01  18.71500015258789   19.940357208251953  18.299285888671875  19.859643936157227  17.332521438598633  5225155600  
2013-12-01  19.928571701049805  20.540714263916016  19.242856979370117  20.036428451538086  17.588905334472656  7057397200  
2014-01-01  19.845714569091797  20.007143020629883  17.626785278320312  17.878570556640625  15.694639205932617  8765954400  
2014-02-01  17.95035743713379   19.68535614013672   17.832143783569336  18.794286727905273  16.49850082397461   5880366800  
2014-03-01  18.693571090698242  19.60714340209961   18.671785354614258  19.169286727905273  16.928415298461914  5001698800  
2014-04-01  19.205713272094727  21.408214569091797  18.26178550720215   21.074642181396484  18.61104393005371   6435060800  
2014-05-01  21.14285659790039   23.006071090698242  20.726070404052734  22.60714340209961   19.964397430419922  5735668400  19.760982275009155
2014-06-01  22.641429901123047  23.762500762939453  22.23214340209961   23.232500076293945  20.631237030029297  4827739200  20.331562757492065
2014-07-01  23.3799991607666    24.860000610351562  23.142499923706055  23.899999618530273  21.224002838134766  4140344000  20.836607217788696
2014-08-01  23.725000381469727  25.725000381469727  23.31999969482422   25.625  22.755857467651367  3748308000  21.535178661346436
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File E:\Praveen\Python\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File e:\praveen\technical team\four panel chart\candlestick_fpc.py:46
    mpf.plot(apple_ohlc_2, type='candle', ax=ax[0,0], style='yahoo', xrotation=0, addplot=ap)

  File E:\Praveen\Python\lib\site-packages\mplfinance\plotting.py:429 in plot
    external_axes_mode = _check_for_external_axes(config)

  File E:\Praveen\Python\lib\site-packages\mplfinance\_arg_validators.py:446 in _check_for_external_axes
    raise ValueError('make_addplot() `ax` kwargs must all be of type `matplotlib.axis.Axes`')

ValueError: make_addplot() `ax` kwargs must all be of type `matplotlib.axis.Axes`
```

I'm encountering challenges when trying to plot a Simple Moving Average (SMA) line on top of a Candlestick chart using mplfinance in Python. Although I initially attempted to use the 'mav' argument, I couldn't find a straightforward way to add a legend for the SMA line. As an alternative approach, I've calculated the SMA data using the close price and aim to incorporate it while plotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplfinance as mpf


ticker_symbol = "AAPL"

start_date_1 = "2013-09-24"
end_date_1 = "2023-09-24"

start_date_2 = "2017-09-24"
end_date_2 = "2023-09-24"

start_date_3 = "2022-09-24"
end_date_3 = "2023-09-24"

start_date_4 = "2023-03-24"
end_date_4 = "2023-09-24"


apple_ohlc_1 = yf.download(ticker_symbol, start=start_date_1, end=end_date_1, interval="1mo")
apple_ohlc_1["8-Month SMA"] = apple_ohlc_1["Close"].rolling(8).mean()
apple_ohlc_2 = yf.download(ticker_symbol, start=start_date_2, end=end_date_2, interval="1wk")
apple_ohlc_2["40-Week SMA"] = apple_ohlc_2["Close"].rolling(40).mean()
apple_ohlc_3 = yf.download(ticker_symbol, start=start_date_3, end=end_date_3, interval="1d")
apple_ohlc_3["50-Day SMA"] = apple_ohlc_3["Close"].rolling(50).mean()
apple_ohlc_3["200-Day SMA"] = apple_ohlc_3["Close"].rolling(200).mean()
apple_ohlc_4 = yf.download(ticker_symbol, start=start_date_4, end=end_date_4, interval="1d")
apple_ohlc_4["50-Day SMA"] = apple_ohlc_4["Close"].rolling(50).mean()
apple_ohlc_4["200-Day SMA"] = apple_ohlc_4["Close"].rolling(200).mean()

fig = mpf.figure(figsize=(30,22), dpi=300)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1,style='yahoo')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2,style='yahoo')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3,style='yahoo')
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,4,style='yahoo')

ap_c18msma = mpf.make_addplot(apple_ohlc_1["8-Month SMA"], color="blue", label="8-Month SMA", ax=ax1)
mpf.plot(apple_ohlc_1, type='candle', ax=ax1, xlabel = "Date", ylabel = "Price($)", axtitle='Apple 10-Year Monthly Chart', xrotation=0, addplot=ap_c18msma, datetime_format='%m/%d/%Y')
ap_c240wsma = mpf.make_addplot(apple_ohlc_2["40-Week SMA"], color="yellow", label="40-Week SMA", ax=ax2)
mpf.plot(apple_ohlc_2, type='candle', ax=ax2, xlabel = "Date", ylabel = "Price($)", axtitle='Apple 5-Year Weekly Chart', xrotation=0, addplot=ap_c240wsma, datetime_format='%m/%d/%Y')
ap_c350200dsma = [mpf.make_addplot(apple_ohlc_3["50-Day SMA"], color="black", label="50-Day SMA", ax=ax3), 
               mpf.make_addplot(apple_ohlc_3["200-Day SMA"], color="pink", label="200-Day SMA", ax=ax3)]
mpf.plot(apple_ohlc_3, type='candle', ax=ax3, xlabel = "Date", ylabel = "Price($)", axtitle='Apple 1-Year Daily Chart', xrotation=0, addplot=ap_c350200dsma, datetime_format='%m/%d/%Y')
ap_c450200dsma = [mpf.make_addplot(apple_ohlc_4["50-Day SMA"], color="black", label="50-Day SMA", ax=ax4), 
                  mpf.make_addplot(apple_ohlc_4["200-Day SMA"], color="pink", label="200-Day SMA", ax=ax4)]
mpf.plot(apple_ohlc_4, type='candle', ax=ax4, xlabel = "Date", ylabel = "Price($)", axtitle='Apple 6-Month Daily Chart', xrotation=0, addplot=ap_c450200dsma, datetime_format='%m/%d/%Y')

plt.tight_layout(pad=10.0, h_pad=2.5, w_pad=2.5, rect=(0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9))

image_path = "Your Location"
plt.savefig(image_path, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1)
plt.close()
```

Thanks to the guidance of @DanielGoldfarb and my research, I've successfully added multiple SMA lines to enhance my candlestick charts.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using mplfinance in [external axes mode](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/external_axes.ipynb) then you must pass **`ax=`** kwargs into ***both* `mpf.plot()` *and* `mpf.make_addplot()`**.

You can see this being done in [**Example 5 of this tutorial**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/external_axes.ipynb).

Comment: I modified the code after your input and got the chart. But the subplots are not in a way it used to be or it has to be. @DanielGoldfarb